# error uploading image from swift to php server

Tags: php, swift, image, post

I have a problem trying to upload an image in swift to a PHP server. Everything looks good till the php processes the file. In that moment I get the error.

The relevant part of the swift code is:

```
func myImageUploadRequest(image: UIImage, realfilename: String)
{

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.ignistudios.com/boda/postImage.php");

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let param = [
        "firstName"  : "username",
        "lastName"    : "lastname",
        "userId"    : "9"
    ]

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
    print(imageData.debugDescription)

    if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

    request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", realfilename: realfilename, imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("******* response = \(response)")

        // Print out reponse body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")



    }

    task.resume()

}


func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, realfilename: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    var body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    let filename = realfilename

    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")



    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}




func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
}
```

And the php is

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/fotos/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
echo "<p>";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
  echo "Upload failed";
}
echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

And last, the error I get is:

****** response data =

Upload failed

```
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Optional(\"boda20160428_135709.jpg\")
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )
```

)

Any tip would be very much appreciated.

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php  error#1 = file size exceeds limit set in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Marc B has commented with the answer which is that it is a PHP file upload size issue.

However in cases like this it is worth testing each link in the chain separately. For example testing and reviewing the output of createBodyWithParameters. Create a test and run it there to check that the headers are properly formed. Especially make sure that the string encoding is correct. I'm not familiar with the `appendString` method on `NSMutableData`.

It should be possible to feed that output more directly into the server to eliminate other potential issues.

Comment: Thanks joseph. Once the max_size problem is superated, I'm getting the error => 0 now but the upload still fails. The traces says almost nothing: ****** response data =  
<p>Upload failed</p><pre>Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => img.jpg
            [type] => image/jpg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phppWL1iR
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 66605
        )

)
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that the image is too big and you need to compress the image before uploading it, using this

```
 UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.2)
```

When the image is small enough you will get your tmp name